# FastAPI: Permanently running background task that listens to Postgres notifications and sends data to websocket

Tags: postgresql, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import asyncio
import aiopg
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket


dsn = "dbname=aiopg user=aiopg password=passwd host=127.0.0.1"
app = FastAPI()


class ConnectionManager:
    self.count_connections = 0
    # other class functions and variables are taken from FastAPI docs
    ...


manager = ConnectionManager()


async def send_and_receive_data(websocket: WebSocket):
    data = await websocket.receive_json()
    await websocket.send_text('Thanks for the message')
    # then process received data


# taken from official aiopg documentation
# the function listens to PostgreSQL notifications
async def listen(conn):
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
        await cur.execute("LISTEN channel")
        while True:
            msg = await conn.notifies.get()


async def postgres_listen():
    async with aiopg.connect(dsn) as listenConn:
        listener = listen(listenConn)
        await listener


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.websocket("/")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    manager.count_connections += 1

    if manager.count_connections == 1:
        await asyncio.gather(
            send_and_receive_data(websocket),
            postgres_listen()
        )
    else:
        await send_and_receive_data(websocket)
```

Description of the problem:

I am building an app with Vue.js, FastAPI and PostgreSQL. In this example I attempt to use listen/notify from Postgres and implement it in the websocket. I also use a lot of usual http endpoints along with the websocket endpoint.

I want to run a permanent background asynchronous function at the start of the FastAPI app that will then send messages to all websocket clients/connections. So, when I use `uvicorn  main:app` it should not only run the FastAPI app but also my background function `postgres_listen()`, which notifies all websocket users, when a new row is added to the table in the database.

I know that I can use `asyncio.create_task()` and place it in the `on_*` event, or even place it after the `manager = ConnectionManager()` row, but it will not work in my case! Because after any http request (for instance, `read_root()` function), I will get the same error described below.

You see that I use a strange way to run my `postgres_listen()` function in my `websocket_endpoint()` function only when the first client connects to the websocket. Any subsequent client connection does not run/trigger this function again. And everything works fine... until the first client/user disconnects (for example, closes browser tab). When it happens, I immediately get the `GeneratorExit` error caused by `psycopg2.OperationalError`:

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=OperationalError('Connection closed')>
psycopg2.OperationalError: Connection closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-18' coro=<Queue.get() done, defined at 
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/queues.py:154> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
```

The error comes from the `listen()` function. After this error, I will not get any notification from the database as the asyncio's `Task` is cancelled. There is nothing wrong with the `psycopg2`, `aiopg` or `asyncio`. The problem is that I don't understand where to put the `postgres_listen()` function so it will not be cancelled after the first client disconnects. From my understanding, I can easily write a python script that will connect to the websocket (so I will be the first client of the websocket) and then run forever so I will not get the `psycopg2.OperationalError` exception again, but it does not seem right to do so.

My question is: where should I put `postgres_listen()` function, so the first connection to websocket may be disconnected with no consequences?

P.S. `asyncio.shield()` also does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered this on Github as well, so I am reposting it here.

A working example can be found here:
https://github.com/JarroVGIT/fastapi-github-issues/tree/master/5015

```py
# app.py
import queue
from typing import Any
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from asyncio import Queue, Task
import asyncio

import uvicorn
import websockets

class Listener:
    def __init__(self):
        #Every incoming websocket conneciton adds it own Queue to this list called 
        #subscribers.
        self.subscribers: list[Queue] = []
        #This will hold a asyncio task which will receives messages and broadcasts them 
        #to all subscribers.
        self.listener_task: Task

    async def subscribe(self, q: Queue):
        #Every incoming websocket connection must create a Queue and subscribe itself to 
        #this class instance 
        self.subscribers.append(q)


    async def start_listening(self):
        #Method that must be called on startup of application to start the listening 
        #process of external messages.
        self.listener_task = asyncio.create_task(self._listener())

    async def _listener(self) -> None:
        #The method with the infinite listener. In this example, it listens to a websocket
        #as it was the fastest way for me to mimic the 'infinite generator' in issue 5015
        #but this can be anything. It is started (via start_listening()) on startup of app.
        async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8001") as websocket:
            async for message in websocket:
                for q in self.subscribers:
                    #important here: every websocket connection has its own Queue added to
                    #the list of subscribers. Here, we actually broadcast incoming messages
                    #to all open websocket connections.
                    await q.put(message)

    async def stop_listening(self):
        #closing off the asyncio task when stopping the app. This method is called on 
        #app shutdown
        if self.listener_task.done():
            self.listener_task.result()
        else:
            self.listener_task.cancel()

    async def receive_and_publish_message(self, msg: Any):
        #this was a method that was called when someone would make a request 
        #to /add_item endpoint as part of earlier solution to see if the msg would be 
        #broadcasted to all open websocket connections (it does)
        for q in self.subscribers:
            try:
                q.put_nowait(str(msg))
            except Exception as e:
                raise e

    #Note: missing here is any disconnect logic (e.g. removing the queue from the list of subscribers
    # when a websocket connection is ended or closed.)

        
global_listener = Listener()

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    await global_listener.start_listening()
    return

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await global_listener.stop_listening()
    return


@app.get('/add_item/{item}')
async def add_item(item: str):
    #this was a test endpoint, to see if new items where actually broadcasted to all 
    #open websocket connections.
    await global_listener.receive_and_publish_message(item)
    return {"published_message:": item}

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    q: asyncio.Queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await global_listener.subscribe(q=q)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await q.get()
            await websocket.send_text(data)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

As I didn't have access to a stream of message I could have subscribed to, I created a quick script that produces a websocket, so that the app.py above could listen to that (indefinitely) to mimic your use case.

```py
# generator.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
import asyncio
import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            await websocket.send_text(f"Hello - {i}")
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            i+=1
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```

The app.py will listen to a websocket and publishes all incoming messages to all connections to the websockets in app.py.

The generator.py is a simple FastAPI app that has a websocket (that our example app.py above listens to) that emits a message every 2 seconds to every connection it gets.

To try this out:

- Start generator.py (e.g. python3 generator.py on your command line when in your working folder)
- Start app.py (either debug mode in VScode or same as above)
- Listen to http://localhost:8000/ws (= endpoint in app.py) with several clients, you will see that they will all join in the same message streak.

NOTE: lots of this logic was inspired by Broadcaster (a python module)

Comment: Is there a way i could send message to a connection instead of all connections?